# Simulation leads to dump?

Tags: c

I am a newbie for *C* and need help to figure out the problem when I did simulation.

It works very well when I run 10 times simulation. However, the error message shows **segementation fault (core dumped)** when I run 100 times simulation. Thank you for your help in advance for helping to solve this problem.

BTW, my code is really long (around 1000 lines) and ugly. If who can help, I am more than happy to offer my code for your review.

Thanks,
Jane

Comment: Can you try to reduce your code to a smaller example exhibiting the problem and post that ? In fact reducing the code to a smaller version might be just what it takes to find out what's wrong yourself.

Comment: just following from the comment above, welcome to the world of software development....  C programmers often face "1000" lines of code thats doing something crazy.   The first thing you have to do is isolate the code down.   Debug it, print out things to a console, start commenting out code etc till you can find a smallish chunk thats giving you the grief

Comment: oh, and also, unit testing helps build nice chunks of working code.... like using the brilliant *cough* not biased at all *cough* seatest unit testing framework  https://code.google.com/p/seatest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add trace printing and/or learn how to use a debugger like GDB and its GUI front-end DDD. You need to test your code and nail down where it fails and learn proper debugging techniques.

You can not just look at all your code like a box and say that it does not work. You need to establish what works and what is not working.

A segfault means that you are handling memory wrong somewhere, accessing memory that are outside of the memory this program is allowed to access.

Since this is a beginner question I will take the opportunity to promote my suggested Q&A site for beginner programmers. Where simple questions are OK and met with a positive constructive advice. If you like the idea become a [follower](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52242/beginner-programmers?referrer=YHFcRobXPDGfDpFmz1HCvA2)